# Moment Generating Function: Pulling a term out of k-times differentiation

Tags: stochastic-calculus

In *Wiersema: Brownian Motion Calculus* on p. 205 (in an Annex on Moment Generating Functions (mgf)) the following equation is being presented $${d^k \over d\theta^k} \left ({1\over k!}\theta^k\mathbb{E}[X^k]\right)={1\over k!}\theta^k{d^k \over d\theta^k} \mathbb{E}[X^k]$$ with $X$ being a random variable, $\theta$ the mgf-dummy variable and $\mathbb{E}$ the expectation operator (and $k$ for the $k$'th moment of $X$).
**My question**: Why is it possible to pull the term ${1\over k!}\theta^k$ out and in front of the $k$-times differentiation? Could anyone give me a hint or some intermediate steps? Or is this a typo? (Sorry if this is too elementary but I don't get it anyway - and I want to understand this!)

Comment: are you *sure* about this? For a start, $X$ presumably doesn't depend on $\theta$, so if anything it should be the $k$th moment of $X$ that you can pull outside the differentiation

Comment: Since this seems to be a typo, and moreover quite a localized question, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's clearly a typo.  Unless I misunderstand the point of this, the right formula should be
$${d^k \over d\theta^k} \left ({1\over k!}\theta^k\mathbb{E}[X^k]\right)={1\over k!}\mathbb{E}\left[{d^k \over d\theta^k} \theta^k X^k\right]$$

In fact, this is what is said in words before the formula in the book you mentioned:

> The $k$th moment can be singled out by differentiating $k$ times with respect to $\theta$, and interchanging the differentiation and $\mathbb{E}$ (which is an integration)

Comment: Thank you - why are you allowed to do *that* (interchanging differentiation and $\mathbb{E}$)? And why are you allowed to pull out the ${1\over k!}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}$ is a linear operation.  It is after all integration with respect to a probability measure.  The parameter $\theta$ is auxiliary -- it is a constant from the point of view of integration.